# How to mock imported component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to write test for a wrapper component which holds children `<Example/>` component.
And there is a heavy mocking going on in `<Example/>`. What I am trying to achieve is to put mocked `<Example/>` inside `<Parent/>` without having to do mocking stuff again.

pseudo code
`test('test', () => { //there somehow need to swap component that is imported inside Parent render(<Parent/>) })`

Comment: see https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Comment: Show the code. What have you tried? What did you get?

Comment: @slideshowp2 child component has a lot of logic that needs to be mocked, but i dont want to repeat testing it in it's own test and when testing parent

Comment: It's not clear. You can mock the complex child component when testing the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using functional components, you can mock children components by adding this code at the top of your test file :

```
// Each occurrence of ChildComponent in the tested component
// will be mocked with a div, with a data-testid attribute and
// its props in a data-props attribute
jest.mock('/path/to/child/ChildComponent', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ChildComponent: (props: any) => (
    <div data-testid="mocked-child-component" data-props={JSON.stringify(props)}>
      Mocked Child Component
    </div>
  ),
}));
```

So you can test that `ChildComponent` exists when testing the parent component, by searching for the data-testid (or the text in the div), and check that the props passed to ChildComponent by the component under test are correct :

```
const getProps = (element: HTMLElement): Record<string, unknown> => JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-props'));

[...]

// check that parent component is passing correct props to its child
rtl = render(<ParentComponent />));
expect(getProps(rtl.getByTestId('mocked-children-component'))).toEqual({...});
```